# Does there exist an Epimorphism such that $\phi: F^{n} \rightarrow F^{m}$ where $n>m$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Does there exist an Epimorphism such that $\phi: F^{n} \rightarrow F^{m}$ where $n>m$. 
My attempt:
 Suppose there exist an epimorphism, then the $\text{Im}(\phi) = F^{m}$ by rank and nullity theorem $n = m+ \text{Nullity}(\phi)$. From here i dont know what to do. 
 
 Or are there any counterexample to this!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is such an epimorphism $\phi$. Just define$$\phi(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=(x_1,\ldots,x_m).$$